# Doctrine Query cache and event listener

Tags: symfony, caching, doctrine-orm

I have an event listener in order to filter by user :

```
class UserFilter extends SQLFilter
{   
  public function addFilterConstraint(ClassMetadata $targetEntity, $targetTableAlias)
  {
    ...
    return $targetTableAlias.'.createdBy = ' .$this->security_context->getToken()->getUser()->getId(); 
  }             
}
```

It's good on dev environment, but the filter is not called on prod environment, except for the first call

In the `config_prod.yml`, I have:

```
doctrine:
  orm:
    metadata_cache_driver:
        type: memcache
        host: localhost
        port: 11211
        instance_class: Memcache
    query_cache_driver:
        type: memcache
        host: localhost
        port: 11211
        instance_class: Memcache
```

If I comment `query_cache_driver`, I don't have this issue ...
I think `query_cache` disable the call to the filter listener, how can I solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use query cache, the whole sql query building process is skipped. What you should do is not to use filter, but pass in the user id to your function, and bind it to the query as parameter. The real problem here, is that you didn't use it as parameter, but as 'string', and that part is cached with query caching.
If you can bind the parameter also at the eventlistener as Parameter, then that can work also.

You can try maybe what is described [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/filters.html#disabling-enabling-filters-and-setting-parameters)

Comment: i use sqlfilter in order to not pass the user_id to all function (many entities, many functions, ...)
and i am not sure you can bind a parameter with sqlfilter (the addFilterConstraint must return string)

Answer (score 0):

Here `addFilterConstraint` must return string but you can set some parameters just to avoid caching issue.

Maybe solution is to set some random parameter inside filter just to trigger cache.

```
$this->setParameter('cache', $random);
```